# Unknown Query Engine Error ; Failed to open a rowset ; Error in .rpt file

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal report which is having a data source from MS SQL server. I am always getting this error when we want to show the report:

> Unknown Query Engine Error
>
> Failed to open a rowset.
>
> Error in File C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\student{ED5C2412-C7A1-4E1D-8093-1EFDA02340ABD}.rpt:
>
> Unknown Query Engine Error

I have checked the connection too. No problem with it.

Can any one help me?

In extension to this question I found a problem which was caused by one column of the table in the report. When I remove that field it is working fine. When the report is migrated from Access to MS SQL server source, it is converted using cross join. Is this raised from table linking only?

Comment: Does it work when you preview the report from the designer?

Comment: no throwing the same error :-(

Comment: I have tried by removing formula fields one by one

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if this is relevant but try the solution given in this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/5ae1b14e-ad6f-4093-baa2-a5d65a8a0bf0) . The solution suggests you add this line to your config file :

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
```

Comment: @JaiGanesh verify that your datasource has no problem. did you do that?

Comment: @JaiGanesh check [this](http://support.resortdata.com/Customers/Knowledge/KB-RDPWin/KWin0025.htm)